# R gender package - Range of Years

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I am trying to use the gender package to predict gender by first names.  I do not have birthdate data, so I'm trying to use a range of dates for the gender package to reference.  But, I get this error.

> Error: year_col %in% names(data) are not all TRUE

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
myData <- read.csv("Firstnames.csv",
               header = TRUE)

 names_df <- data_frame(names = myData$First.Name,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 gender_df(names_df, method = "ssa", name_col = "names", year_col = c("1932","2012"))
```

Documentation
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/gender.pdf

Comment: 1. No data provided = downvote

Comment: 2. Format the code nicely in the OP